# Using Vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

how do i insert `<char>` arrays into `<char*>` vectors something like this:

```
std::vector<char> ch;
ch.push_back('H');
ch.push_back('e');
ch.push_back('l');
ch.push_back('l');
ch.push_back('o');

std::vector<char*> vec;
vec.push_back(ch);
```

but it gives error saying : `push_back() cannot convert parameter 1 from....`
So is there a way to load `ch[]` values into `vec[0]` and still use one of my function which searches for the contents in the vector for example:
`vecf[]` contains a file contents in it, i can search through the `vecf[0]vecf[1]...` for a similar content like searching a text `"Hello"` from `"Hi, Hello..."`?

As I was told my Question was unclear, So here is the clearer version:
It is Possible to do like this:

```
char string[]="Hello World";
std::vector<char*> vec;
vec.push_back(string);
cout<<vec[0];
```

then if a string is of type std::vector like this:

```
std::vector<char> string;
std::vector<char*> vec;
how would i do like this?
vec.push_back(string);
```

or something like this to get the contents of string into vec, and ch and vec is not in the real project, i used the term ch and vec for just an example to how to do like this, in my project theres a char vector variable ID which is something like this ID="ID2" but in vector, the ID's values is loaded from a file, there is another tag which contains refering ID which i will compare with the ID[0]/ID[1] until one matches if one matched i will get its position on array, then theres another vector variable(int) which contains all the nodes position of array in the file, i will use like this SPos[ArrayPos] to get the position of the node in the file, hope this was clear enough...

Comment: Why don't you just use string in C++?

Comment: Why are you using `char*` in the first place?

Comment: It's indeed `std::string` that you are looking for, if you want to keep vector for some reason it's `int len = strlen(ch); std::vector<char> vec; vec.insert(vec.begin,ch,ch+len);`. Oh and what failed for you was the conversion from `const char *` to `char *`

Comment: @aga_pan Im more familiar with chars instead a string, and im using char* Because a <char*> can store values like "Hello world", a whole string can just be displayed as cout<<string[0], not like <char> which gives compiler error while doing like this: cout<<string, if we want to view all the contents we would have to show it manualy or from a for()/while() loop like cout<<string[0]<<string[1](manually) etc... so is there a way loading a <char> contents into <char*> and still search for a specific content in them?

Comment: @DeEp_FrEeze: No, that is not correct. Why do you think that? See a working example of printing a string here: http://ideone.com/kYTowC

Comment: @PeterT would'nt it give a compiler error because vec<char> ch; is'nt a string? at most i recieved errors saying ch is a struct/class, and it was solved when i do like this ch[0], and the error was conversion from a struct/class to a char*

Comment: `vec.push_back(ch.data())` except you won't be able to print it to `cout`, because your char array is not null-terminated.

Comment: @DeEp_FrEeze - I don't know where you're learning C++, but what you stated is all wrong concerning `std::string`.

Comment: I find your question very unclear, however it sounds like you need a `std::string` and not a `std::vector`. You can do all the `s[0];` style indexing on `std::string` as well as printing them out whole using `std::cout << s;`.

Comment: thanks @BenjaminLindley to refering me to ideone.com site, and i know what to do now, i will do like this in my project std::vector<string> vec and this will store values like "Hello world", and actually im learning c++ at home, no teacher is here for teaching me, i learned c++ by my own but using another library i hates it, and i prefer using chars, but beause theres no way to do something like this vec.push_back("Hello World") automaticaly through vec.push_back(ch) i will use string instead, thanks for all your help especially Benjamin for helping me understand what a string is...

Comment: Recommend you get a good book: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score -1):

```
std::vector<char*> vec;
```

This says that vec is a vector of char*.

But you are trying to insert a vector. There is no automatic conversion possible here.

Assuming you really do not want to use string type, you would want to declare

```
std::vector<std::vector<char> > vec;
vec.push_back(ch);
```

Please note that, if you want pointers to vector to be stored, you have to have allocate ch on the heap.

Comment: but it still gives errors like "no operator defined to take the right hand operand..." when doing cout<<vec[0]; in short i want to do like this: to get the contents of ch into vec, because vec is built from char pointers and it can contain strings like vec[0] and can be easily viewed but i want to convert a char into char* pointers, your example works but it cannot show like this cout<<vec[0], hope you understand

Comment: That is a slightly separate concern. vec[0] results in a vector<char>. "cout << vec[0]" won't work as there is no such method. Based on your requirements it seems either you want to convert vector<char> into a string or just use string type directly.